# How can a 2.1 Hz excitation induce resonant vibrations in a structure with a fundamental frequency at 6.3 Hz?

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform, resonance, vibrations, harmonics

I've come across an example given in a footfall design guide wherein it's mentioned that a floor with a fundamental frequency of 6.3 Hz can be excited to resonance by a person walking at 2.1 Hz through the third harmonic.

My question is, how exactly does this work? Why would a structure be susceptible to excitation (and specifically, resonant excitation) by a forcing function at a much lower frequency?

Comment: Footsteps are not a sine wave. Consider instead more of a square wave, which clearly will have many harmonics of the fundamental frequency.

Comment: @JonCuster That looks like it should be an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Footsteps are not a pure sine wave at all. Consider them instead as more of a square wave, which clearly will have many harmonics of the fundamental frequency. Assuming a more complicated wave function to describe the impact of footsteps will still have many harmonics of the fundamental.

Comment: Thanks Jon ! This pretty much clears the whole thing up.

Comment: Or, graphically, picture a lazy dad who  pushes his kid on a swing by pushing only on every *third* swing...